# How to create new blank project in maui

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui, .net-maui, maui-windows

How can i create new blank project in maui? When im creating new project i dont have window to pick theme. I searched all internet and I really dont know how to do or change that.

Comment: Have you definitely got the MAUI workload installed in your version of VS 2022? (I'm not quite sure what you mean by "dont have window to pick theme"...)

Comment: When I create first project i had window to pick theme, there was blank, tabbed and flyout. When im trying creating new project i dont have that window and i cant change template. It looks like it saved my choice.

Comment: I don't remember ever seeing that option... so am I right in saying you *can* create a new MAUI project, it's just that you're not getting as many options to choose from as you expected? (Your question makes it sound like you can't create an empty MAUI project at all...)

Comment: There should be option like that: https://prnt.sc/WIEc9iyO9-z9

Comment: And I can create only project with basic template. Maybe I can change that in VS but i really dont know how.

Comment: That is the XF template.  I don’t think MAUI has all the same options

Comment: So is it possible to create blank project in MAUI? Or only with basic template?

Comment: At this time, it would be challenging to correctly build a Maui project completely "from scratch". So, take what it does. Delete the default MainPage and/or Shell if don't need.

Comment: For now i use visual studio preview for MAUI to get onboard :)

Comment: And what do you mean blank MAUI project? for me blank project is blank, not related to any framework, then the dev creating such project would add dependencies and choose frameworks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean create a MAUI app, or create one from a template. There is no blank template, but to create a MAUI app in the first place you must have at least Visual Studio 2022 version 17.3.0, and installed the MAUI workload (via the installer). If you have that version with workload, then you can create a new MAUI app (you can find it quicker if you set Project type to MAUI (see screenshot).

[image]

It won't be blank though - as usual you get a demo app instead of a blank app (sigh), so if you want a blank app you have to strip out the stuff you don't want (and you can then make your own template from that to use going forward).